# Returning the Position of a Pandas Dataframe Entry when first Value in the Row equals 1

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, comparison

As described above i want to get the Position Index  of the Dataframe entry based on the condition. It should look something like this

```py
import pandas as pd
a = [[1,0,0,1],[0,1,0,1],[0,0,0,1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df

Out[61]: 
    0  1  2  3
 0  1  0  0  1
 1  0  1  0  1
 2  0  0  0  1
```

And i want to create a new column, that returns the position of the first 1 of the corresponding row. So the End result should look like this:

```py
Out[62]: 
    0  1  2  3  New
 0  1  0  0  1  0
 1  0  1  0  1  1
 2  0  0  0  1  3
```

This is my first Question on stackoverflow, so sorry if i did some formal mistakes while asking this question. 
Any help appreciated

Comment: `final=df.assign(New=df.idxmax(1))`

Comment: df.idxmax(1)   em